# How to set default y axis value when data not exists in particular x axes in flot chart

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

[image]I have generated a flot chart by using data points. I didn't use ticks for x and y axes. The reason is my data set will vary huge.

Now flot chart generate the graph well. But it breaks in between the ticks, when there is no data.
How can i set default y axis value if there is no data exists?

Comment: It would be nice with a fiddle showing the problem :)

Comment: @Margo, Please check this fiddle link. I would like to see the line to go 0 when there is no value.      http://jsfiddle.net/rajan416/zrfLth6z/1/

Comment: According to the data you provide, the fiddle looks correct.  Can you be a little more specific about "it breaks in between the ticks"? What do you mean by "break"?  Explain what you mean by this and we may be able to help you better.

Comment: @CaptainBli, I have added the image for the reference.

Comment: Do you own/control the data points? If you do then I'd suggest generating a data point for the dates where no data was generated. If you don't then you could post-process the data to add the empty dates.

Comment: @BenSmith, I don't have the control to data points since the date range will vary based on user inputs. I let the flot to draw the data points for me... Now how can i post process the data. All I need is default value for ticks which doesn't have data points. Is this possible in the flot library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert datapoints with zero value between your existing data points when they are more than one day apart. I created this function for that:

```
function prepareData(data) {
    if (data && data.length > 0) {
        var oneDay = 86400000;
        var newData = [];

        // new zero value point before the old first point
        newData.push([(parseInt(data[0][0], 10) - oneDay).toString(), "0"]);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // add existing point to new data
            newData.push(data[i]);

            // check distance between this point and the next (if not last point)
            if (i < data.length - 1) {
                var thisPointTimestamp = parseInt(data[i][0], 10);
                var nextPointTimestamp = parseInt(data[i + 1][0], 10);

                // if distance is two days, insert ony zero value point in between
                if (nextPointTimestamp - thisPointTimestamp == 2 * oneDay) {
                    newData.push([(thisPointTimestamp + oneDay).toString(), "0"]);
                }
                // if distance is more than two days, insert one zero value point
                // directly after this day and one directly before the next day
                else if (nextPointTimestamp - thisPointTimestamp > 2 * oneDay) {
                    newData.push([(thisPointTimestamp + oneDay).toString(), "0"]);
                    newData.push([(nextPointTimestamp - oneDay).toString(), "0"]);
                }
            }
        }

        // new zero value point after the old last point
        newData.push([(parseInt(data[data.length - 1][0], 10) + oneDay).toString(), "0"]);

        return newData;
    }
}
```

See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrfLth6z/2/) for the full example. Or this code snippet:

```js
 var responseCountData, datasets;

 function displayGraph() {

   responseCountData = response = {
     "alertCount": {
       "RED": [
         ["1397433600000", "1"],
         ["1397520000000", "2"],
         ["1400457600000", "1"],
         ["1400544000000", "5"],
         ["1401148800000", "1"],
         ["1407456000000", "1"],
         ["1407715200000", "1"],
         ["1408406400000", "1"],
         ["1408492800000", "1"],
         ["1409097600000", "3"],
         ["1409097600000", "4"],
         ["1409097600000", "2"],
         ["1409184000000", "1"],
         ["1409184000000", "1"],
         ["1409184000000", "1"],
         ["1409270400000", "4"],
         ["1409270400000", "2"]
       ],
       "YELLOW": [
         ["1397433600000", "2"],
         ["1397433600000", "1"],
         ["1397520000000", "1"],
         ["1397606400000", "1"],
         ["1400457600000", "1"],
         ["1400544000000", "1"],
         ["1401148800000", "2"],
         ["1406246400000", "5"],
         ["1406246400000", "2"],
         ["1406505600000", "2"],
         ["1406505600000", "1"],
         ["1406592000000", "1"],
         ["1406678400000", "1"],
         ["1407456000000", "1"],
         ["1407456000000", "1"],
         ["1408406400000", "1"],
         ["1409097600000", "1"],
         ["1409097600000", "1"],
         ["1409184000000", "1"]
       ],
       "GREEN": [
         ["1397433600000", "2"],
         ["1397433600000", "1"],
         ["1400025600000", "1"],
         ["1400457600000", "1"],
         ["1401148800000", "1"],
         ["1407456000000", "1"],
         ["1407715200000", "3"],
         ["1409270400000", "1"]
       ],
       "TOTAL": [
         [0, 0]
       ]
     }
   };
   var responseCount = responseCountData['alertCount'];
   datasets = {
     "Green": {
       data: prepareData(responseCount.GREEN),
       label: "Green flag",
       color: "#00CC33"
     },
     "Yellow": {
       data: prepareData(responseCount.YELLOW),
       label: "Yellow flag",
       color: "#FFFF00"
     },
     "Red": {
       data: prepareData(responseCount.RED),
       label: "Red flag",
       color: "#FF0000"
     },
     "Total": {
       data: responseCount.TOTAL,
       label: "Total number of flags",
       color: "#0000FF"
     }
   };
   plotAccordingToChoices();
 }

 function prepareData(data) {
   if (data && data.length > 0) {
     var oneDay = 86400000;
     var newData = [];

     // new zero value point before the old first point
     newData.push([(parseInt(data[0][0], 10) - oneDay).toString(), "0"]);

     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       // add existing point to new data
       newData.push(data[i]);

       // check distance between this point and the next (if not last point)
       if (i < data.length - 1) {
         var thisPointTimestamp = parseInt(data[i][0], 10);
         var nextPointTimestamp = parseInt(data[i + 1][0], 10);

         // if distance is two days, insert ony zero value point in between
         if (nextPointTimestamp - thisPointTimestamp == 2 * oneDay) {
           newData.push([(thisPointTimestamp + oneDay).toString(), "0"]);
         }
         // if distance is more then two days, insert one zero value point
         // directly after this day and one directly before the next day
         else if (nextPointTimestamp - thisPointTimestamp > 2 * oneDay) {
           newData.push([(thisPointTimestamp + oneDay).toString(), "0"]);
           newData.push([(nextPointTimestamp - oneDay).toString(), "0"]);
         }
       }
     }

     // new zero value point after the old last point
     newData.push([(parseInt(data[data.length - 1][0], 10) + oneDay).toString(), "0"]);

     return newData;
   }
 }


 function plotAccordingToChoices() {

   var data = [];
   data.push(datasets["Green"]);
   data.push(datasets["Yellow"]);
   data.push(datasets["Red"]);
   $.plot("#placeholder", data, {
     xaxis: {
       show: true,
       mode: "time",
       timeformat: "%m/%d"
     },
     yaxis: {
       show: true,
       tickDecimals: 0
     },

     grid: {
       hoverable: true //IMPORTANT! this is needed for tooltip to work
     },
     tooltip: true,
     tooltipOpts: {
       content: function(label, x, y) {
         var date = new Date(+x);
         console.log(x, date);
         var tooltip = '<h4>' + label + '</h4><ul>';
         tooltip += '<li>Date is ' + date.toLocaleDateString() + '</li>';
         tooltip += '<li>Total Count: ' + y + '</li></ul>';
         return tooltip;
       },
       defaultTheme: false
     },
     points: {
       show: true
     },
     series: {
       lines: {
         show: true,
         label: {
           show: false
         }
       },
       points: {
         show: true,
         label: {
           show: false
         }
       }
     },

     legend: {
       show: false
     }
   });
   var container = $("#placeholder");
   // Create the X and Y axis labels
   var xaxisLabel = $("<div id='xaxisLabel' class='axisLabel xaxisLabel'></div>")
     .text("Date")
     .appendTo(container);

   var yaxisLabel = $("<div id='yaxisLabel' class='axisLabel yaxisLabel'></div>")
     .text("Total Count")
     .appendTo(container);
 }

 $(function() {
   displayGraph();
 });
```

```css
.demo-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 850px;
  height: 450px;
  padding: 20px 15px 15px 15px;
  margin: 15px auto 30px auto;
  background: #fff;
}
.demo-placeholder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
.legend table {
  border-spacing: 5px;
}
.axisLabel {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.yaxisLabel {
  top: 50%;
  left: -30px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.ie7 .yaxisLabel,
.ie8 .yaxisLabel {
  top: 40%;
  font-size: 36px;
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0.0, M12=0.33, M21=-0.33, M22=0.0, sizingMethod='auto expand');
}
.xaxisLabel {
  top: 105%;
  left: 47%;
}
#content {
  width: 880px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}
#chartModal {
  display: block;
}
#xaxisLabel {
  margin-top: 65%;
}
#yaxisLabel {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: -5%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.flot.tooltip/0.7.1/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.benjaminbuffet.com/public/js/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade action-modal ajax-modal enabled-modal modal-handler" id="chartModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width:1000px">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="content">
          <div class="demo-container">
            <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder" style="float:left; width:675px;height:415px"></div>
            <div style="float:right;position:absolute; padding-left: 680px"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```